# Is けど a 接続詞 (conjunction) or 助詞 (particle)?

Tags: grammar, particles, terminology, conjunctions

A book I've read states that けど is a 接続詞 (conjunction).

However, another book I had read states that it is a 助詞 (particle).

Who is right?

Comment: けど is a particle or adverb semantically bridges clauses. I'm not sure what OP expects from the question, especially in what difference would be made whether けど were a "conjunction" or a "particle".

Comment: @broccoliforest, A terminology question. Is けど a 接続詞 or 助詞?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, being 接続詞 and 助詞 are not mutually exclusive in Japanese. I've found a perfect explanation in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_%28grammar%29#Subordinating_conjunctions Since morphology is overwhelming in Japanese, every word must declare its role morphologically. So asking about a word "conjunction" or "particle" is like asking an Asian American man whether he is "Asian" or "American".

Comment: Dictionaries list けど as both a 接続助詞 and as a 接続詞, depending on whether it's following a clause or beginning a sentence.  Some list it as a 終助詞 as well.

Comment: I looked up in dictionaries, and see they treat けど, でも, しかも etc. as 接続詞. It somehow seems like they think all words used between two sentences are 接続詞. In fact these words behave like _however_ in "That is, however, a misunderstanding." In this sense, が and だが are only examples I find to be counterpart of English _conjunction_. Mmm, I really should have a grammar book in my house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

けど is a conjunction.It is not a  particle.
In conjunction with… …と関連［接続］して； …と合同［連絡］して, …とともに. and けど is  also 接助・終助.

adverbial particles 副詞的小詞 《on, in, out, over, off など》.

Comment: @Pacerier If it attaches to a noun, then it is a particle; if it attaches to a clause, then it is a conjunction.

Comment: ＠sawa not necessarily true. What about sentence ending particles?